# Comunicação Bidirecional - Como obter status?

Tags: c#, socket

Biblioteca que eu utilizo: https://github.com/rdavisau/sockets-for-pcl

*Segue código:*

### Servidor:

```
static async Task Run()
{
    var listenPort = 11000;
    var listener = new TcpSocketListener();
    listener.ConnectionReceived += async (sender, args) =>
    {
        var client = args.SocketClient;
        var reader = new StreamReader(client.ReadStream);
        var data = await reader.ReadLineAsync() + "\n";
        var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
        await client.WriteStream.WriteAsync(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        await client.WriteStream.FlushAsync();
    };

    await listener.StartListeningAsync(listenPort);
}
```

### Cliente:

```
static async Task Run()
{
    var address = "127.0.0.1.2.4";
    var port = 11000;

    var client = new TcpSocketClient();
    var connectionTask = client.ConnectAsync(address, port);
    connectionTask.Wait(5000);

    if (connectionTask.IsCompleted)
    {
        //
    }

    var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Olá mundo\n");
    await client.WriteStream.WriteAsync(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    await client.WriteStream.FlushAsync();

    var reader = new StreamReader(client.ReadStream);
    var data = await reader.ReadLineAsync();
    Console.WriteLine(data);
}
```

As vezes você pode digitar endereço **Ip Server** errado, para isso, preciso verificar o status da conexão. A propriedade `IsCompleted` sempre retorna como `false`, alguma solução de como posso obter o status da conexão ?

Comment: Qual é o package do `TcpSocketClient()`?

Comment: @LeandroAngelo https://github.com/rdavisau/sockets-for-pcl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está chamando um método assíncrono, esperando 5 segundos e depois tentando ler um atributo que pode não estar refletindo seu estado real. E você também não está capturando o erro ao tentar conectar. veja o metodo alterado

```
public async Task Run()
{
    var address = "127.0.0.1.2.8";
    var port = 11000;

    using (var client = new TcpSocketClient())
    {
        try
        {
            await client.ConnectAsync(address, port);

            if (client.Socket.Connected)
            {
                var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Olá mundo\n");
                await client.WriteStream.WriteAsync(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                await client.WriteStream.FlushAsync();

                var reader = new StreamReader(client.ReadStream);
                var data = await reader.ReadLineAsync();
                Console.WriteLine(data);
            }
        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }

    }
}
```