# Como descobrir se TCP Listener está ouvindo?

Tags: c#, socket, tcpclient

Biblioteca que eu utilizo: https://github.com/rdavisau/sockets-for-pcl

Segue código:

```
await client.ConnectAsync(address, port);
```

O código acima é o cliente e funciona normal. Digamos que o servidor está desligado, quando executo o código acima, ela demora pouco tempo e recebo erro:

> Connection timed out

Demora uns 3 minutos para executar essa exceção. Existe alguma forma de saber se o servidor está ouvindo antes de executar o código acima ? Ou então diminuir 3 minutos para 5 segundos.

Aqui tem a resposta de como obter o status: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/285103/54019

Comment: muda o timeout ?

Comment: em `system.net.sockets.tcpclient` basta alterar: `TCPClient.ReceiveTimeout = 5000; TCPClient.SendTimeout = 5000;`  Nesse que você está usando, deve haver um equivalente

Comment: é porque está usando uma biblioteca diferente, eu não a conheço e não sei se é igual à `system.net.sockets.tcpclient`. Só isso =]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode alterar o `Timeout` do client:

```
TCPClient.ReceiveTimeout = 5000; 
TCPClient.SendTimeout = 5000;
```

> Observe que um timeout muito curto pode causar problemas durante a comunicação.

Comment: Rovann, seu código só funciona no modo síncrono. Agora que eu percebi :/

Comment: No modo assíncrono tive que fazer assim: `await client.ConnectAsync(address, port, true, new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)).Token);`